# Swift. UISegmentedControl

Tags: swift

Как сделать так чтобы в SegmentedControl убрать ободок вокруг сегментов? А также добавить вторую строку в каждом сегменте чтоб выглядело это примерно так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы

Answer (score 1):

### Что случилось

К сожалению, [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol) для решения этой задачи не подходит. В документации написано, что он умеет отображать картинку и одну строку текста.

### Что делать

Рекомендую воспользоваться [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) для горизонтального размещения элементов. В качестве элемента можно использовать кнопку [UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton), разместив в ней текст необходимым образом. К каждой из кнопок можно добавить свой обработчик нажатий.

### Подробнее

#### Шаг 1. Кнопка с несколькими текстами

```swift
final class TwoLinesButton: UIButton {
    let title = UILabel()
    let subtitle = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }
    
    private func initialize() {
        // Настраиваем визуальное отображение текста
        title.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        subtitle.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
        
        [title, subtitle].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview($0)
        }
        
        // Задаём констрейнты, чтобы правильно разместить текст
        // Можно воспользоваться любой другой техникой
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            subtitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            subtitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: title.bottomAnchor),
            subtitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            subtitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        // Обновляем стиль отображения
        updateStyle()
    }
    
    // Метод изменения стиля при выделении кнопки
    // Аналогично можно написать метод для selected состояния
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            guard isHighlighted != oldValue
                else { return }
            updateStyle()
        }
    }
    
    private func updateStyle() {
        let textColor: UIColor = isHighlighted ? .black : .gray
        [title, subtitle].forEach { $0.textColor = textColor }
    }
    
}
```

Заметьте, тут используется метод `UIFont.preferredFont`, чтобы поддержать динамические шрифты из настроек системы.

#### Шаг 2. Использование UIStackView для размещения кнопок

Создадим нужное количество кнопок:

```swift
let buttonFrame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 100))
let buttons = (0 ..< 5).map { _ in TwoLinesButton(frame: buttonFrame) }
```

Расположим кнопки в стеке:

```swift
let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttons)
stack.axis = .horizontal
stack.distribution = .fillEqually // Одинаковые по ширине
stack.alignment = .fill // Сверху до низу
```

Зададим нужные значения текстов в кнопках:

```swift
buttons.enumerated().forEach {
    $1.title.text = "Some text \($0)"
    $1.subtitle.text = "Some text \($0)"
}
```

### Результат

[image: Использование кнопок UIButton с двумя строками в стеке UIStackView]

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо самостоятельно создать новый класс на основе UIControl или UIView.

Примеры можете посмотреть тут:

[HBSegmentedControl](https://github.com/hilalbaig/HBSegmentedControl)

[How Create a Custom Segmented Control — Swift](https://medium.com/code-with-coffee/create-a-custom-segmented-control-6488400f8705)

[CustomSegmentedControl](https://github.com/Code-With-Coffee/CustomSegmentedControl)